# is there WiX logic: if (OSLanguage==en-US)

Tags: localization, wix

in WiX .wxs file, we just can do things without 'if' logic.
is there any logic in WiX as:

```
if (OSLanguage==en-US)
{
    copy file1 to dir1
}
else if(OSLanguage==zh-CN)
{
    copy file2 to dir2
}
else if(OSLanguage==de-DE)
{
    copy file3 to dir3
}
else
{
    copy file4 to dir4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put file1 in a component being installed to dir1 and give it a condition of SystemLanguageID=1033.

Similarly with the other files in their own components.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372056(v=vs.85).aspx

In a per user install it could make more sense to use UserLanguageID in case the user is using one language and the OS is another.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372384(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: would you give an small example since I'm not familiar with WiX grammar

Answer (score 0):

i got a solution, as following.
we can use Condition when copying files.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
  <Component Id="resources.dll.zh_HANS" Guid="B7F590B2-1F3F-441E-B16F-EEF7AE240502">
    <Condition>UserLanguageID=2052</Condition>
    <File Id="resources.dll.zh_HANS" Source="E:\share\tmp\res\res\out\zh-Hans\res.dll" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
```